# BL808 RISC-V (m1s dock) + lvgl example

Tags: lvgl

did somebody  run  m1s with  bouffalo SDK  and LVGL (ILI9488 or other) ?

I connected the ILI9488 display to it, I run them as an example of LVGL, the display passes initialization, but does not display graphics, I even compared the initialization and sending of data with the ESP32, I checked the log analyzer, everything is basically identical, but it does not work on this microcontroller.

if I change the pixel format to 18 bits, then a distorted rendering appears on the screen, with a 16 bit pixel format the screen is just gray. this should work with 16 bit  pixel format

Is it spi driver or lv_port_disp.c problem?